# Solving a system of unknowns in terms of unknowns

Tags: r, math, matrix

I am trying to solve a 5x5 Cholesky decomposition (for a variance-covariance matrix) all in terms of unknowns (no constants).

A simplified version, for the sake of giving an example, would be a 2x2 decomposition:

```
[[a,0],[b,c]]*[[a,b],[0,c]]=[[U1,U2],[U2,U3]]
```

Is there a software (I'm proficient in R, so if R can do it that would be great) that could solve the above to yield an answer of the left-hand variables in terms of the right-hand variables? i.e. this would be the final answer:

```
a = sqrt(U1)
b = U2/sqrt(U1)
c = sqrt(U3+U2/U1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky.E2.80.93Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky.E2.80.93Crout_algorithms).

The symbolic definition of the (i,j)th entry of the decomposition is defined recursively in terms of the entries above and to the left. You could implement these recursions using [Matlab's Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/) and then apply them (symbolically) to obtain your formulas for the 5x5 case. Be warned that you'll probably end up with **extremely** complicated formulas for some of the unknowns, and - excepting unusual circumstances - it will be fine to implement the decomposition iteratively even for a fixed size 5x5 matrix.